# Does order matter in context free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

let say i have the follow grammar:

> ```
> expr = expr + term | term    
> term = term +  number | number    
> number = (just any integers..)
> ```

My question is, is **expr = expr + term | term** same as **expr = term + expr | term**?

I expanded the grammar, and it seems does matter. am i correct?

Comment: No it's not the same. Order matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not the same. Order matters. For examples look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Example

Answer (score 0):

The answer, of course, is that it depends on the grammar.

In your case, replacing one rule for the other does not change the set of strings in the language generated by the grammar. The grammar is different, but the language is the same. The only difference is that the first builds strings from the right, and the second builds strings from the left.

It's not hard to come up with grammars where this does not work: sometimes, changing the order of symbols in a production will change the language.